# Unable to persist all values of map in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, dictionary, annotations

Layout of database:

USER_PREF_VAL

1. int user_id
2. int value_id
3. int pref_id

USER

1. int id
2. varchar name

PREF_VAL

1. int id
2. int pref_id
3. varchar value
4. varchar label

PREF

1. int id
2. varchar name
3. varchar label

   ```
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(
       name="CMS_USER_PREFERENCE_VALUE",
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="user_id" ),
       inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="value_id")
   )
   @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
   @MapKey(name = "preference")
   public Map<PreferenceEntity, PreferenceValueEntity> getPreferences(){
       return map;
   }
   protected void setPreferences(Map<PreferenceEntity, PreferenceValueEntity> mp){
       map = mp;
   }

   public void addPreference(PreferenceEntity pe,PreferenceValueEntity pve){
       map.put(pe,pve);
   }
   ```

My problem is that, when pulling out the information using getPreferences()

I get the correct mapping of items from USER_PREF_VAL
Namely: MAP /PreferenceEntity, ValueEntity\

However when I do an add, in the database it will create a row such as:

USER_ID, PREFERENCE_ID, NULL

Any help on figuring out how to get that value to be probably inserted would be greatly appreciated. Also I know that the value being passed to as the ValueEntity is not null.

Thank you

Comment: Is the relationship between the two object bidirectional?  If so, you need to set the parent reference in the child or vice-versa.